# How to merge dataframes on one column while aligning the other columns in common

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider two DataFrames:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    'bar': ['w','x','y','z','h'],
                    'foo': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E']})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10],
                    'foo': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'I','J','K']})
```

Imagine we want to join DataFrames on `'key'` so that ONLY the keys in df1 are returned EXCEPT for those keys in df2 that are greater than 8.  You can do this by

1. first doing a left join via `df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='key',how='left')`
2. Then, doing an outer join with a slice of df2 via `df4 = pd.merge(df3,df2.loc[df2['key']>8],on='key',how='outer')`

However, rather than aligning the columns `'foo'` in each DataFrame, each 'foo' column will be added to df4 as discrete columns with suffixes added to distinguish between them.  And, several lines of code will be required to combine the three `'foo'` columns so that I have a DataFrame with only one `'foo'` column.  Is there a more concise way to do this?

**EDIT:**

I guess my example belies the true question.  Let's use these DataFrames:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    'bar': ['w','x','y','z','h'],
                    'foo': [np.nan, np.nan, 'C', 'D','E'],})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10],
                    'foo': ['A', 'B', np.nan, 'I','J','K']})
```

If I use a left and then outer join as described above, I will get this...

```
key bar foo_x   foo_y   foo
0   1   w   NaN A   NaN
1   2   x   NaN B   NaN
2   3   y   C   NaN NaN
3   4   z   D   NaN NaN
4   5   h   E   NaN NaN
5   9   NaN NaN NaN J
6   10  NaN NaN NaN K
```

Because combining the three `'foo'` columns will require many lines of code, I wondering if there is a more concise do all this.  That is, merge the two DataFrames and combine the `'foo'` columns such that the returned DataFrame is this:

```
    key bar foo
0   1   w   A
1   2   x   B
2   3   y   C
3   4   z   D
4   5   h   E
5   9   NaN J
6   10  NaN K
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try `concat` and `groupby`:

```
(pd.concat((df1, df2.query('key>8')))
   .groupby('key',as_index=False).first()
)
```

Output:

```
   key foo  bar
0    1   A    w
1    2   B    x
2    3   C    y
3    4   D    z
4    5   E    h
5    9   J  NaN
6   10   K  NaN
```

Comment: Although this works for the first set of DataFrames, I edited the question and added two different DataFrames that better exemplify what I am actually trying to do.  For the new DataFrames, this solution does not work.